# How to reindex a pandas DataFrame after concatenation

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I concatenate two DataFrames like so:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

array1 = np.random.randn(3,3)
array2 = np.random.randn(3,3)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1, columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2, columns=list('ABC'))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

The resulting DataFrame `df` looks like this:

```
          A         B         C
0  1.297362  0.745510 -0.206756
1 -0.056807 -1.875149 -0.210556
2  0.310837 -1.068873  2.054006
0  1.163739 -0.678165  2.626052
1 -0.557625 -1.448195 -1.391434
2  0.222607 -0.334348  0.672643
```

Note that the indices are the same as in the original DataFrames. I'd like to re-index `df` such that the indices simply run from `0` to `5`. How can I do this?

(I've tried `df = df.reindex(index = range(df.shape[0]))` but this gives `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. This is because the original axis contains duplicates (two `0`s, two `1`s, etc.)).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want to pass `ignore_index=True` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
In [68]:
array1 = np.random.randn(3,3)
array2 = np.random.randn(3,3)
​
df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1, columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2, columns=list('ABC'))
​
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
df

Out[68]:
          A         B         C
0 -0.091094  0.460133 -0.548937
1 -0.839469 -1.354138 -0.823666
2  0.088581 -1.142542 -1.746608
3  0.067320  1.014533 -1.294371
4  2.094135  0.622129  1.203257
5  0.415768 -0.467081 -0.740371
```

This will ignore the existing indices so in effect it sets a new index starting from 0 for the newly concatenated index

Answer (score 0):

Using EdChum's set up

```
array1 = np.random.randn(3,3)
array2 = np.random.randn(3,3)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(array1, columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(array2, columns=list('ABC'))

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

[image]

Comment: you may want to add `inplace=True` to the `reset_index()` call unless you're assigning the output to a new variable